# How to trouble shoot "Don't know how to get path data from object of class standardGeneric" with leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial

I am trying to create a map showing generation capacity by county with leaflet. There can be multiple generating units per county, but I thought that would not be an issue for mapping county capacity. I pulled county geometries from tidycensus, and joined those with the dataset for county generation capacity. I have included my code below. Any help/insight would be much appreciated!

```
  Texas_counties <- get_acs(state = "TX", geography = "county", 
                      variables = c(totalpop = "B01003_001"), geometry = TRUE)

  Texas_counties <- Texas_counties %>%
  mutate(NAME = gsub(" County, Texas", "", NAME))

  Texas_counties <- Texas_counties %>%
    mutate(NAME = toupper(NAME))
  Texas_counties$GEOID <- NULL
  Texas_counties$variable <- NULL
  Texas_counties$estimate <- NULL
  Texas_counties$moe <- NULL

  colnames(Texas_counties)[1] <- "COUNTY"

  ERCOT_counties <- left_join(ERCOT_report, Texas_counties, by = "COUNTY")

  pal <- colorNumeric("viridis", NULL)

 leaflet(ERCOT_counties) %>%
 addTiles() %>%
 addPolygons(data = geometry, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, 
 fillOpacity = 1,
           fillColor = ~pal(COUNTY_CAPACITY))
```

`Error in polygonData.default(data) :  Don't know how to get path data from object of class standardGeneric`

Comment: You are passing the parameter `data = geometry` to `addPolygons`. Where is `geometry` coming from? You don't seem to have that defined anywhere. Maybe you meant `data = ~geometry`?

Comment: Geometry is coming from Texas_counties. It is pulled in as a part of the get_acs function where geometry = TRUE

Comment: Then you need to use the `~` before the name to let leaflet know the values are coming from the data object

Comment: I do that and then I get "Don't know how to get path data from object of class formula"...when I run str(ERCOT_counties), it returns geometry as a sfc_Multipolygon

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't have the contents of your `ERGOT_report` data frame, it's hard to know, but my guess is that you're getting that error because you're using a simple data frame and not an `sf` or spatial data frame in your `leaflet()` call.

Whenever possible, I find it easiest to have my data and spatial features together in one `sf` object. So here is an example of how you would get the county geometry from [tigris](https://github.com/walkerke/tigris), join it with a non-spatial data frame (I just made up some data here) and then make a map. Note when you are joining a spatial data frame and a non-spatial data frame, the order of the join matters. So if you want to output of your join to be spatial, the first data frame must be the `sf` object and the second is the non-spatial data frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(tigris)
library(sf)

# get county geometries using tigris
tx_counties <- counties(state = "TX", cb = TRUE) %>% 
  transmute(COUNTY = toupper(NAME))

# create some made up data for 50 of the tx counties
ercot_report <- tibble(
  COUNTY = tx_counties$COUNTY,
  COUNTY_CAPACITY = rpois(nrow(tx_counties), lambda = 10)
  ) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 50)

# join geometry to data
ercot_counties <- tx_counties %>% 
  inner_join(ercot_report) %>% 
  st_transform(4326)

# create palette to use in leaflet map
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "viridis",
  domain = ercot_counties$COUNTY_CAPACITY
  )

# map!
leaflet(ercot_counties) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE,
    smoothFactor = 0.3, 
    fillOpacity = 1,
    fillColor = ~pal(COUNTY_CAPACITY)
    )
```

[image: texas county leaflet map]